# VI Editor in Ubuntu 12.4.2 (LTS)

Tags: vim, 12.04

I have recently got a copy of Ubuntu 12.04.2(LTS), but unfortunately problem occurs while trying VI editor. I have heard that VIM (VI improved) should be installed in order to use vi in this version. If this is the case then is there any way to install it OFFLINE? Is there any alternate editor that can be used to write shell scripts or C source programs.

Comment: The `vi` command that ships with Ubuntu is the _tiny_ version of Vim. What "problem" do you have with it?

Comment: Also, your question is more about your Ubuntu system environment, not about programming, so it's better addressed at SuperUser.

Comment: I can execute shell commands there. Can also evoke the vi editor using vi [filename]. But I have problem with the modes in the editor which doesn't work for me. @IngoKarkat

Comment: Are you uncomfortable with modal editing in general? Type `vimtutor` to get an introduction. Or try a more straightforward editor like `nano`.

Comment: Just a suggestion if you may. Try gedit instead

Answer (score 1):

The package for the terminal version of Vim is named `vim`. You can download it and its dependencies [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/vim). You need to at least also install the `vim-common` and `vim-runtime` packages.

There's also a GUI version of Vim, the package name is `vim-gnome`.

Comment: thnks, I also want to know whether it can be done just offline,I mean downloading first,because the machine where ubuntu is installed has no internet connection @Ingo Karkat

Comment: The download links are at the bottom of the linked page; you can choose between 32-/64-bit versions. The will get you a `*.deb` file which you can then install with `dpkg -i *.deb`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `vi` come with Ubuntu12.04 is `vim tiny` or something like that which is not fully featured one. You can install it offline, get a `deb` package for vim and copy it to your machine, use `dpkg -i your_deb_package`.

Comment: thnxx @john smith , I have to try it,where do I get a deb package? You are right,but some of the modes in the editor doesn't work properly..

Comment: you may found it here. look for vim gnome. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim

Answer (score 0):

The `vi` command is available by default on *every* UNIX-y operating system, including Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

On Debian-based systems like Ubuntu, `vi` is not the original `vi` but a lightweight Vim build that usually lacks a few useful features like clipboard or scripting support.

You are not very clear about the "problem" that "occurs". Without more information, we can't do much more than provide generic advices.

- If you are *really* unable to install/update your programs your only solution is to customize your Vim config as well as you could. Run the following command in a terminal emulator:

  ```
  $ touch ~/.vimrc
  ```

  You should now be able to use the `vim` command with saner defaults. After that, you are on your own for the rest of the learning curve.
- If you are able to update/install programs, use the Synaptic package manager or `apt-get` to install the `vim-gnome` or `vim-gtk` package which are much more complete than the default build.

  Once the installation is complete, create a `~/.vimrc` like above and enjoy the ride.

Comment: I mean to say commands pertaining to the modes like :i, :x aren't working properly.For example,in input mode I can't use backspace to delete some characters, the keys behave abnormally. @romainl

Comment: Not all version of Ubuntu includes `vim`/`vi`. The user has to install it normally in 13.04.

Comment: @rosemary. The backspace behaviour is default vi behavior. You must do quite a lot of configuration if you want it to behave "normally". Your vim works perfectly: no need to reinstall it!